Error-the identity property on the argument is null or empty
I'm creating powershell scripts which is to get members from nested security groups in Active Directory.
Some group has members from multi domains.
I ran individually, and it works well.
Could you please tell me how to fix an error.
The error is "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'.
The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again."
Below is overall script.

  $csvpath = "xxxxx.csv"
  $parentgroups =Import-Csv -Encoding Default $csvpath

  $filepath = "xxxxxxx.csv"

  //Get users from nested group
  function ShowUser ($group){

  $dn = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $group).DistinguishedName  //Error occurred in this line
  $members = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(memberOf=$dn)"
  $Table = @()

  Foreach($member in $members){

  if($member.ObjectClass -eq "user"}{
  $Record = [PSCustomObject]@{
  SubSecurityGroup = $group
  UserAccount = $member.SamAccountName
  }
  $Table = $Record
  $Table | Export-Csv -Append -Path $filepath -NoTypeInformation
  }
  elseif ($member.objectClass -eq "group") {ShowUser ($member.SamAccountName)}
  }
  }

  //Below is main component
  Foreach($parentgroup in $parentgroups){
  ShowUser ($parentgroup.MailingList)
  }

I ran each line of the script individually, and it didn't throw any errors at that time.

If Identity is showing giving error that it is null, then this probably means that MailingList from your csv file is coming in as null.  Anyways, I will post an answer of this code a bit cleaned up and you can try it and see if anything improves.

There appears to be some errors in placement of parentheses and braces.  Also some unnecessary assignments.  Comments in PowerShell start with # and not //
Try out this refactor of your code and see if there is any improvement.  My thoughts on the error though is that MailingList is not populating from your csv when you import.  Do all lines in the csv have a MailingList value?
# Function to get users from nested groups
function ShowUser($Group) {
    $dn = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $group).DistinguishedName 
    Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(memberOf=$dn)" -Properties SamAccountName | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $member = $_
            if ($member.ObjectClass -eq 'user') {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    SubSecurityGroup = $group
                    UserAccount      = $member.SamAccountName
                } 
            }
            elseif ($member.objectClass -eq 'group') { 
                ShowUser -group $member.SamAccountName
            }
        } 
}


$csvpath = 'xxxxx.csv'
$filepath = 'results.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $csvpath | ForEach-Object {
    $parentGroup = $_
    ShowUser -Group $parentGroup.MailingList
} | Export-Csv -Append -Path $filepath -NoTypeInformation


